# How to make an entry longCond above a moving average with other conditions?

Tags: pine-script

Ok I have got this far, and it's almost there, just need help making this plotted entry as I have searched Google far and wide and opened a support ticket with tradingview but I'm still unsure as to how to fix this issue. It may even be an easy fix but I'm new to pinescript and looking for any help possible.

The entry I made is only allowed to trigger above the 400hma and every time a candlestick is crossing back up the 49 HMA. And only start after the first initial 400hma/49hma crossing. But it seems to be triggering for every instance and each and every candlestick and I'm unsure of how to make it trigger only once for every time it crosses back up the 49HMA? As it hovers above the 400hma.
If that makes sense Lol. Please help and Big time thanks!

I have attached a photo to show the entry point I am trying to achieve for reference.
The circled candlestick should be the only plotted entry point. It is the first candlestick to crossover the 49hma after the initial breakout over the 400hma.
I hope this helps.

```
//@version=4 
strategy ("15MinChart400", overlay=true) 

hma23 = hma(close, 23) 
hma49 = hma(close, 49) 
hma16 = hma(close, 16) 
hma400 = hma(close, 400) 

long = close >= hma400 
exitLong = close <= hma400 


longCond = (close >= hma400) and (close >= hma49) 


plotshape(series=longCond, title="BUY", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=#00AEFF, text="BUY", size=size.small) 

plot(hma16, title = "16", color=#FFFFFF, linewidth=1) 
plot(hma23, title = "23", color=#00AEFF, linewidth=2) 
plot(hma49, title = "49", color=#9E1BD1, linewidth=2) 
plot(hma400, title = "400", color=#E1DE2D, linewidth=3) 



strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 1, when = long) 
strategy.close("long", when=exitLong)
```

Any help would be so awesome!

Paul
[Photo of Desired Entry Trigger Placement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4zLC.jpg)

Comment: `plotshape(strategy.position_size == 0? longCond : na, title="BUY", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=#00AEFF, text="BUY", size=size.small) `

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question it helped a lot!

Comment: Now I'm trying to plot a stop loss and having trouble doing so. I would like to plot the price of the low of the current candle while this candle is crossing over the hma49.

Comment: I know it's a plotshape function but I keep getting errors.

Comment: Any help would be fantastic! Thanks
And thanks for the help already.